# prepare(for:sender:) not getting called

Tags: swift, segue, xcode8-beta6

I downloaded Apple's MyLife sample project and attempted to build and run it using Xcode 8 beta 6.

There are two places where a view controller has implemented the `prepare(for:sender:)` call to do stuff before a storyboard segue is performed.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

That line has an error saying "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

If I remove the override, the app builds but the method isn't called when it should be.

Comment: Did you try "Edit -> Convert -> To Latest Swift Syntax ..." ?

Comment: It's already a Swift 3 project, just not the very *latest* version of Swift 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method signature has changed. `sender` is now `Any?` instead of `AnyObject?`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

This is to coincide with the changes to how Swift is bridged with obj-c, described [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_6/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_6.pdf) under "New in Xcode 8 beta 6 - Swift Compiler"

Comment: Just discovered that myself. Also for whatever reason it's not showing up in autocomplete.